# coffeescript is not executing code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to have my click function change the CSS code and then execute a function. This is the code i currently have:

```
ready: ->
   $("#titleDD").click ->
     $("#titleDD").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
     $("#catDD").css('text-decoration', 'none');    
   $("#catDD").click ->
     $("#catDD").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
     $("#titleDD").css('text-decoration', 'none'); 
     `console.log("hello2");`
     `console.log("hello");`
```

When I run the code, the console immediately shows hello2 and hello as soon as my webpage starts to run.  When I click on the #catDD hello and hello2 are not printed and titleDD text-decoration does not change.  Can anyone explain why all of the code is not executing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ready: ->
   $("#titleDD").click ->
     $("#titleDD").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
     $("#catDD").css('text-decoration', 'none');   
     return 
   $("#catDD").click ->
     $("#catDD").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
     $("#titleDD").css('text-decoration', 'none'); 
     console.log "hello2"
     console.log "hello"
     return
   return
```

Generates:

```
  ready: function() {
    $("#titleDD").click(function() {
      $("#titleDD").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
      $("#catDD").css('text-decoration', 'none');
    });
    $("#catDD").click(function() {
      $("#catDD").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
      $("#titleDD").css('text-decoration', 'none');
      console.log("hello2");
      console.log("hello");
    });
  }
```

(sorry im anal about my returns in coffeescript -- they generate extra js if you're not careful, no one want to see `return console.log("hello");` at the end of the function)

Comment: Why would removing the backticks or adding a `return` change when the `console.log` calls are made? `console.log` doesn't return anything so `return console.log('x')` and `console.log('x'); return` should be functionally equivalent, no?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes. Like i said, anal, i just dont like to see it, unless there is a need to return something, i dont like it to return the last line with a `return` on it. As for the issue, i dont know, i dont see how the console is being executed as soon as the document loaded and not after a `click` event. I figured OP repasting my code would at the very lease cause another error and he would finally have his eureka moment :P Also, i dont like ` unless ABSOLUTELY necessary